# iOS Change VOIP payload on runtime Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip, pushkit

I want to modify the payload of VOIP before showing calling screen. I am getting number instead of name when getting call notification (VOIP Push). Is there a way to change the payload on frontend? That delegate trigger every time when I get call.

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {}
```

Comment: You can get the data from the `payload` as a `NSDictionary` with `payload.dictionaryPayload`. Can you alter the data in that before passing it to `TwilioVoiceSDK.handleNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and changed it in my server that handles the calls. There is a parameter that you can use "CallerId" and in there you can set the name of the caller instead of that random number that Twilio generates. It does cause a warning on the Twilio logs though. This was done in nodejs.

```
Caller = request.body.Caller.split(":").pop();
const dial = voiceResponse.dial({CallerId: Caller});
```